# i need a help how can i treat maximum call stack?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Thanks i fixed some sentence by advice. my code is like that,

i wanna find object with id. but if not, I want to return 'null'

```
    function ha7(arr, id) {  // i wanna find object with id 

    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
      if(arr[i].id === id) {   
        return arr[i]   // found id, then return included object
      }
    else if(Array.isArray(arr[i].children)){ // but , its array
       // let ar = ha7(arr[i].children, id)
        result.push(...arr[i].children)      // i put 'arr[i].children' to variables 
      } 
    }
      if (result.id === id) {
        return result                      //  find object with id in inner
 
      } else {
        return ha7(result, id)             // cant find. then go ahead! 
      }
    return null                            // all of none exist id is return null
    }
```

it is testing array.

```
    let input = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'johnny',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'ingi',
        children: [
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'johnson',
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            name: 'steve',
            children: [
              {
                id: 6,
                name: 'lisa',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            id: 11,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '13',
      },
    ];

    output = ha7(input, 5);
    console.log(output); // --> { id: 5, name: 'steve', children: [{ id: 6, name: 'lisa' }] }

    output = ha7(input, 99);
    console.log(output); // --> null
```

I tried a lot of trial, like that. i wanna know.
how can i treat maximum call stack ?
and i wanna return 'null' value.

```js
function ha7(arr, id) {  // i wanna find object with id 

    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
      if(arr[i].id === id) {   
        return arr[i]   // found id, then return included object
      }
    else if(Array.isArray(arr[i].children)){ // but , its array
       // let ar = ha7(arr[i].children, id)
        result.push(...arr[i].children)      // i put 'arr[i].children' to variables 
      } 
    }
      if (result.id === id) {
        return result                      //  find object with id in inner
 
      } else {
        return ha7(result, id)             // cant find. then go ahead! 
      }
    return null                            // all of none exist id is return null
    }
    
    let input = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'johnny',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'ingi',
        children: [
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'johnson',
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            name: 'steve',
            children: [
              {
                id: 6,
                name: 'lisa',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            id: 11,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '13',
      },
    ];

    output = ha7(input, 5);
    console.log(output); // --> { id: 5, name: 'steve', children: [{ id: 6, name: 'lisa' }] }

    output = ha7(input, 99);
    console.log(output); // --> null
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, can you share the whole message?

Comment: @Brian McCutchon "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded." messege is  like that when i run my engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is the problem:

```
   if (result.id === id) {
        return result                      //  find object with id in inner
 
      } else {
        return ha7(result, id)             // cant find. then go ahead! 
      }
```

Two lines above this you initialize `result` as an array. Then in this conditional test you treat the array `result` as if it were an object. So, since `result.id` does not equal `id`, the else condition recurses for ever and ever.

I've taken a different, more functional approach to the task.

1. filter the array on the id

   - If there is a length then at least one was found
   - Return the first one
2. Next filter out all the objects with children
3. Then create an array (with `.map()` that only includes the children
4. This will create an array of arrays, so must flatten it
5. If there are no children, then `id` was not found

   - Return null
6. Recurse the children

   ```js
   let input=[{id:1,name:"johnny"},{id:2,name:"ingi",children:[{id:3,name:"johnson"},{id:5,name:"steve",children:[{id:6,name:"lisa"}]},{id:11}]},{id:"13"}]; 


   function ha7(arr, id) {
     let found = arr.filter(o => o.id === id);
     if (found.length) return found[0]; // return first match
     let children = arr.filter(o=>!!o.children).map(c=>c.children).flat();
     if(!children.length) return null;
     return ha7(children, id);
   }

   output = ha7(input, 5);
   console.log(output); // --> { id: 5, name: 'steve', children: [{ id: 6, name: 'lisa' }] }

   output = ha7(input, 99);
   console.log(output); // --> null
   ```

Comment: Ohhhhhh thank you soo much...!! how to find that problem ? could you give me some tip ?  i couldn't notice well..using google debugger ?

Comment: Sure. First I saw this: `let result = [];` (result is array), then I saw this: `result.push(...)` (ok, result is still array), then I saw _this_: `result.id === id` (WAIT - trying to use result like an object, but it still an array, so `result.id` doesn't equal `id`.  That's it. The solution I provided avoids the pit falls of misusing variables since there is no mutation involved - we always have clean results from these functions.

Comment: Ohhhhhh thank you sooo much :)  thanks to your favor.

Comment: My pleasure. Have fun.